# ReactTestUtils.Simulate.mouseDown

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, simulate, mousedown

I'm trying to use the React Simulate function to simulate a mouseDown event for testing.

```
(defn mouse-down [node]
   ((.-mouseDown(.-Simulate ReactTestUtils) node (clj->js {:button 0})))
```

js translation:

```
ReactTestUtils.Simulate.mouseDown(node, {button: 0})
```

Nothing I've tried has resulted in an invocation of the mousedown listener--but when the listener is there when i try it in the browser where it works.  It's just in the simulation.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any stack trace or error logged while you run your tests? I think it could be that there's an extra parens in the function definition, like `((.-mouseDown ...` where it should be `(.mouseDown ...` because with the extra parens you might be calling the return value as a function, which may not be what you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives no good stack trace, and compiles fine and run everything but is not invoking the mousedown listener.  the (.-mouseDown (.-Simulate ReactTestUtils)) actually returns the mousedown fn, which the additional parenthesis then calls with the node & map arugments

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple mistakes in the Syntax here and your parens don't match. Generally it becomes easier if you reorganize the code a bit and `->` can help there. As mentioned in the comment you want to use `.mouseDown` instead of `.-mouseDown`. I opted to use `#js` instead of `clj->js` since that is more optimal for static js objects such as this.

```clj
(defn mouse-down [node]
  (-> (.-Simulate ReactTestUtils)
      (.mouseDown node #js {:button 0})))
```

You can also make this a little more readable depending on where `ReactTestUtils` is coming from. I'm assuming its from the `react-dom` package which you just required.

```clj
;; in your ns
(:require ["react-dom/test-utils" :as ReactTestUtils])

;; which would allow
(defn mouse-down [node]
  (ReactTestUtils/Simulate.mouseDown node #js {:button 0}))

;; or if you are on the latest CLJS version
(:require ["react-dom/test-utils$Simulate" :as sim])

;; and then
(defn mouse-down [node]
  (sim/mouseDown node #js {:button 0}))
```